# how to restore ALL project on Eclipse after the cancellation of .metadata

Tags: eclipse, metadata

Please can you help me to restore all my Java project?
I cancelled .metadata (In first time I put it in the trash can, when I saw the tragedy, I put it in his original place, but I don't see my Java projects).

Can you help me?

Thanks

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new workspace in a different location and import the projects into it as Existing Projects using the Import wizard.